# Set new keyboard shortcuts for switching between desktop activities

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, plasma

Is there a way to set hotkeys for Desktop Activities in KDE Plasma:

[image]

<kbd>Meta/Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is good when there are only two activities; for more, I need a few more hotkeys. Is there a way to set new hotkeys for switching between activities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**KDE Activity Manager shortcuts**

KDE System Settings > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > KDE Component: KDE Activity Manager - Add custom shortcuts

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In KDE Plasma 5.10 it seems to be broken again but the solution was found in [bug-ticket](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=342186)

[image: Custom Shortcats - System Settings]

Check activities list to see theit ID-s:

> qdbus org.kde.ActivityManager /ActivityManager/Activities ListActivities

System Settings -> Shorcuts -> Custom Shortcuts:

For each activity [New] -> Global Shortcus -> DBUS Command

> remote program: org.kde.ActivityManager
>
> remote object: /ActivityManager/Activities
>
> function: SetCurrentActivity
>
> arguments: [paste activity ID]